# How can I change Control's Opacity?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change controls opacity depending on the mouse position on the form, is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the control supports transparent backgrounds, you can use `Color.FromArgb()` to set a translucent color:

```
button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Red);
```

Depending on how you want this to work, you would vary the alpha value based on mouse position (to between 0 and 255).

Comment: This doesn't alter the opacity of the control whatsoever—it simply blends the specified color with the background color inside the control.

Answer (score 2):

Jon B is right, but you can also do it in the Properties window of the WinForms designer. For example, setting the background color to `150, 255, 255, 255` will make the background a translucent white. The designer translates this into `Color.FromArgb(150, 255, 255, 255)` for you.